# How to upload a file starting with Cleanview using net::ftp in perl?

Tags: perl, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file starting with Cleanview and full filename will have random characters in the middle as "Cleanview.45673.log". I need to find file with filename starting with Cleanview and upload. I tried my code as below but its not working. The file is created on the server, but the size is zero bytes. please help.

```
$login = 'abc';
$pass = 'xyz';
$dir = '/projects/ban/android/BX';
$ftp = Net::FTP->new('10.xxx.xx.xxx' ,Debug => 1) or die "Cannot connect";
print("FTP session opened for logs\n");
$ftp->login($login, $pass) or die "Can't log $login in\n";
$ftp->pasv();
$ftp->cwd($dir);
my @cleanviewlog = glob "CleanView*.log";
$ftp->pasv;
for(@cleanviewlog)
{
 print "Transferring CleanView log $_\n";
 $ftp->put("$_") or die $ftp->message;
 sleep(5);
}
```

Here is the debug message shown:

```
Transferring CleanView log CleanView.66411936.log
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)>>> ALLO 1958
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,131,32,173,161,61)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)>>> PORT 10,32,128,60,230,164
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)<<< 202 ALLO command ignored.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)>>> STOR CleanView.66411936.log
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x202697f0)<<< 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV. PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
```

Comment: I'm not getting please elaborate.

Comment: No, but i've got other files which uploaded fine. For example before the code shown above i have the code which worked fine and files were copied, as:my @getbuildlogs = glob "GetBuildStatus*.log";
my $cleanviewlog = glob "CleanView*.log";

for(@getbuildlogs)
{
 print "$_\n";
 $ftp->put("$_") or die $ftp->message;
 sleep(5);}

Comment: I just did a manual ftp file copy and it worked but with perl script its not working. Please help.

Comment: Define 'not working'. program doesn't die, but no file transferred?

Comment: Not working meant was file was created at the destination but having 0 bytes, thereby no data was transferred.

Comment: Solved the issue. I just places the glob command of CleanView ahead of GetBuild*.log glob command and the file download worked.

Comment: Your problem makes no sense. Your solution makes no sense. Your question mentions no 'GetBuild*'. There is some context you are not explaining. You were probably transferring files before IO buffers were flushed, but you don't mention the zero byte files in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is being transferred, but has zero size, then probably IO is buffered and you are transferring the file after it is created but before the contents of the buffer is flushed. Maybe you need to close the filehandle that creates the file? Or flush the buffer that is writing to the file? There's not enough information in your question to tell for sure exactly what the solution is.